# Rust insists that a generic argument of a cloneable struct must implement Clone, too

Tags: rust

The [documentation of the `Clone` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#derivable) states that "This trait can be used with `#[derive]` if all fields are `Clone`." I'm struggling with a case where all fields *are* `Clone`, and yet deriving `Clone` doesn't work.

Consider the following simplified example ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0436147c59ed36774a13e9dd3c48eb9e)):

```
use std::fmt;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Printer: Clone {
    fn print(&self) -> ();
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ClosurePrinter<T: fmt::Display> {
    get_value: Rc<dyn Fn() ->T>,
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> ClosurePrinter<T> {
    pub fn new(get_value: Rc<dyn Fn() -> T>) -> ClosurePrinter<T> {
        ClosurePrinter { get_value }
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> Printer for ClosurePrinter<T> {
    fn print(&self) -> () {
        println!("{}", (self.get_value)())
    }
}
```

The struct `ClosurePrinter` has a single field, `get_value: Rc<dyn Fn() -> T>`. `Rc` implements `Clone`, so I'm assuming that `get_value` is `Clone`. Yet the compiler insists that `T` must be `Clone`, too:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:19:23
   |
19 | impl<T: fmt::Display> Printer for ClosurePrinter<T> {
   |                       ^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `T`
   |
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `ClosurePrinter<T>`
  --> src/lib.rs:8:10
   |
8  | #[derive(Clone)]
   |          ^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `Printer`
  --> src/lib.rs:4:16
   |
4  | trait Printer: Clone {
   |                ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Printer`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
19 | impl<T: fmt::Display + std::clone::Clone> Printer for ClosurePrinter<T> {
   |                      +++++++++++++++++++
```

Why does the compiler insist that `T` must be `Clone`?

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-deriving-clone-not-work-in-this-case-but-implementing-manually-does/29075)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence in the documentation should explain this

> For a generic struct, `#[derive]` implements `Clone` conditionally by adding bound `Clone` on generic parameters.

This is just how the derive macro works. Moreover it is the only way it *could* work, since procedural macro execution happens before compiler could reason if these trait bounds are necessary. Luckily you can solve this problem, by implementing `Clone` trait manually.

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct ClosurePrinter<T: fmt::Display> {
    get_value: Rc<dyn Fn() ->T>,
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> Clone for ClosurePrinter<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
         let get_value = Rc::clone(&self.get_value);
         Self { get_value }
    }
}
```